# Glade stock buttons unable to change

Tags: application-development, glade

As in title I have a problem with Glade...

Field to change button stock icon or label is not responsive. ( see photos )
I'm running 32bit Ubuntu 12.10 ( it might be a problem ? )

[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to disable **Use Action Appearance**.

Comment: This button was unusable to, I had to add **Related Action** and then change **Use Action Appearance** to No and remove **Related Action** again. 
Thanks Ivan for help!